# Short story about people who wear things to hinder their ability

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story about a dystopia where everything is controlled. It was on a reading list along with *The Veldt*, *Fahrenheit 451*, and *1984*. I can't recall a lot about it except a few scenes. A family is "programmed" and people wear things to hinder their physical/intellectual capability. The family's son rebels against this system and is killed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is almost undoubtedly ["Harrison Bergeron"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron) (1961) by Kurt Vonnegut.

The father is smart, so he wears an ear-piece that makes loud noises at intervals to disrupt his train of thought; the son (Harrison Bergeron) is virtually a super-man, with headphones blasting static into his head, heavy weights to slow him down, prosthetics to make him ugly, etc.

One day he breaks into the ballet, removes his impediments and those of the principal ballerina; they dance beautifully together for a few minutes until they are killed on live TV.